# Filtering find results by length

Tags: linux, find

I want to find all subdirectories inside a single directory. I need to filter by the name length. I have come up with the following:

```
find ./directory -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

How do I filter the results by the name length -- for example, only subdirectories with more than 4 characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `?` wildcard five times:

```bsh
find ./directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '?????*'
```

This requires matches to have at least five characters in their name.

Comment: +1  And for future readers who may want to filter the results of `find` based on a **maximum** filename length, `find ./directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name '?????*'` will find directories with 4 or fewer characters in the name.

Comment: @JimL, with GNU `find` at least, that would also report directory names that contain bytes that can't be decoded into characters regardless of their length.

Comment: Thank you for that detail, @StéphaneChazelas.  I would encourage you to post a general solution that solves the question as titled, rather than the question as stated. I.e., to be able to filter find's results based on a minimum, maximum, or indeed, a range of lengths.

Answer (score 7):

With the `zsh` shell, globs can be filtered by file type (here *directory*) using [*glob qualifiers*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), and with the `extendedglob` option on, you get a `(#cX,Y)` glob operator similar to ERE `{X,Y}`, so you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- ?(#c5,)(ND/)
```

To `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the files of type *directory* (`/` glob qualifier) that are made of `5` or more characters (`?`).

`?(#c5,12)` would be 5 to 12 characters, `?(#c,5)` or `?(#c0,5)` 0 to 5 (not that you can get a filename with 0 characters).

Remove the `D` qualifier if you want to ignore hidden ones.

For `zsh` globs, any byte that cannot be decoded into a character is still considered as one (and will be matched by `?`).

For some `find` implementations including GNU `find`, at least on GNu systems (using the GNU regex / `fnmatch()` from the GNU libc) they will match neither `?` nor  `*` (nor regex `.`) so:

```
find . -maxdepth -name '?????*' -type d
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[^/]{5,}' -type d
```

would fail to match a `$'St\xe9phane'` directory for instance if run in a UTF-8 locale as that 0xe9 byte (ISO8859-1 `é`) cannot be decoded into a character, and there's no workaround other than running `find` under `LC_ALL=C` but then you count the length in bytes instead of characters.

The BSD equivalent of that `-regex` one, would be:

```
find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[^/]{5,}'
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[^/]\{5,\}'
```

(the default being basic regular expressions while for GNU `find`, it's some old emacs regex dialect).

bearing in mind that multibyte character support will vary between variants.

If on a GNU system, another approach is to get `find` to output the file paths NUL delimited (on the ground that NUL is the only character that can't be found in a file path) and `gawk` to filter by length of their name:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%P\0' |
  gawk -v RS='\0' -F/ 'length($NF) > 4'
```

If there are bytes that can't be decoded into characters, `gawk` issues a warning but each of those bytes contribute 1 to the length as with `zsh`.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example of the bug in GNU `find`.  FWIW, BSD `find` appears to handle that particular case correctly (CHARSET=UTF-8), matching on `-name ????????*` but not `-name ?????????*` and likewise, matching on `-not -name '?????????*'` but not on `-not -name '????????*'`.

Comment: @JimL, I suspect your BSD `find` doesn't support multi-byte characters and would find a UTF-8 encoded `ééé` as it has 6 bytes and 3 characters. You may want to clarify which BSD you're using. There's usually significant differences between each.

Comment: I'm happy to test, if you can create an example of how to create such.

Comment: @JimL, check with `locale charmap` that you're in a UTF-8 locale, `touch ééé`, and check which of `find ééé -name '???'`  or `find ééé -name '??????'` returns it.

Comment: As above, charmap is UTF-8. `find ééé -name '???'` matches it, `find ééé -name '??????'` does not. But is it a multi-byte character?  Hex E9 is still a single byte.

Comment: If `touch ééé` does `touch $'\xe9\xe9\xe9'`, your terminal is not UTF-8 (0xe9 is the ISO8859-1 encoding of é while its UTF-8 encoding is 0xc3 0xa9). Try `touch $'\ue9\ue9\ue9'` instead in zsh and verify with `ls | od -tx1` that you get 0c3 0xa9 bytes for each `é`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136381/discussion-between-jim-l-and-stephane-chazelas).